# Open URI / Webbrowser in Main Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I´ve tried to open an URI www.example.com/[scanContent] from within my Activity:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/" + scanContent));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Unfortunately, I got an error: *"URI cannot be resolved"*

Regardless of this error, the method would open the browser externally. How can I open the URI within the Activity ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Then it may be problem with the uri

Comment: Check ur URL properly in the logcat because you mite be leaving a White space some where

Comment: I found the problem: I´ve forgotten to import android.net.Uri; Thank you!